# Intuitive explanation for expected earnings from random walk proportion game

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

A game (from an interview) works as follows:

*In the bank, you have 1 infinitely divisible coin, and flip a coin: if you get a heads, your cash doubles, and if you get a tails, your balance halves. You play this game infinitely. What is your expected earnings?*

The answer is supposedly:

$$\mathbb{E}[X_i] = \frac{1}{2}\frac{X_{i-1}}{2} + \frac{1}{2}2X_{i-1} = \frac{5}{4}X_{i-1}$$ so you expect to make $$\sum_{k=1}^{n} \left(\frac{5}{4}\right)^k \to \infty$$ over an infinite timespan.

But I don't understand intuitively how this is true, because this is essentially a simple random walk over powers of 2, [for which the expected position at time $t+k$ given $t$ is the position at time $t$](https://www.math.uchicago.edu/%7Elawler/reu1).

I was thinking, since I start at $0$ (which means my money is at $2^0$) I expect to be at $0$ in any $n$ turns, which means my money will always be at $2^0$. Why is my intuition incorrect?

Comment: It's not a simple random walk. As the powers of $2$ get larger the steps you take if your balance goes up get larger, they're not constant and balance-goes-up is always a bigger step than balance-goes-down. To make it really clear start by computing your expected earnings after a single flip.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but I thought about it more as "what power of 2 do you expect to be at?" which you _are_ traversing on a simple random walk, no? Why is that framing of the problem not applicable?

Comment: Because the expected value is still given by *adding* up a bunch of powers of two. You're multiplying by two to jump around but adding, not multiplying, to compute the expected value. Again, compute the expected earnings after a single flip.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're thinking in terms of "net displacement", where multiplying by two is a +1 displacement and dividing by two is a -1 displacement. The net displacement is, indeed, a random walk with mean zero.

However, just because expected value of "net displacement" is zero does not mean expected value of X is zero:

$E(X_n) = \sum_{i=0}^{n} \frac{n \choose i}{2^n} 2^{n-2i} = (\frac{5}{4})^n$

Above, $i$ is the number of displacements that were downwards out of $n$ displacements, and $n-2i$ is the net displacement.

In general, if $X=g(Y)$, where $X,Y$ random processes (e.g. $X$ balance, $Y$ net displacement), $E(Y)=0$ does not imply $E(X)=0$.

For this particular problem, maybe you could compare it to the game of blackjack with \$100. In blackjack, if you win, your money is doubled, but if you lose, your ENTIRE \$100 bet is lost. Not just half your bet. Otherwise, the payouts would be +\$100 vs -\$50 which would clearly favor the player.